# PROJETO SCRIPT SQL

Tags: sql

Boa tarde, tenho esse projeto como um trabalho da faculdade, gostaria que alguém pudesse me dar uma luz, dizendo se tem algo errado, ou algo que eu possa melhorar.
Segue o print do que é pedido, e o meu script feito.

Comment: Wííl TR, O SQLite tem uma particularidade por aceitar campos sem definições de tipo. Tome cuidado com isso. Como a resposta do adrianosmateus abaixo, mostra esse caso. O que pode fazer, é executar seu script em outros bancos (pode-se usar o [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/), ou outro), assim te ajudará a captar possíveis inconsistências.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a algumas coisas que observei.

O id da sua tabela `situacao` está sem tipo, então mude a declaração desse id para `id_situacao INTEGER NOT NULL`.

A coluna `id_socio` na tabela `carro` é de um tipo diferente do `id_socio` na tabela `socio`, e isso causará erros. A solução é manter `id_socio` na tabela `carro` também como `INTEGER`

Na sua FK da tabela CARRO, há um pequeno problema de lógica, onde a sua chave estrangeira está sendo montada como `CONSTRAINT  carro_FK FOREIGN KEY (id_socio, id_marca) REFERENCES socio (id_socio, id_marca)` sendo que, dessa forma, o sistema tentará vincular o `id_marca` da sua tabela `carro` com `id_marca` na tabela `socio`, mas como `socio(id_marca)` não existe, não vai funcionar. O certo, para funcionar de acordo com seu modelo, essa fk deveria ser montada assim:

```
CONSTRAINT  carro_socio_FK FOREIGN KEY (id_socio) REFERENCES socio (id_socio),
CONSTRAINT  carro_marca_FK FOREIGN KEY (id_marca) REFERENCES marca (id_marca)
```

Dessa forma, sua tabela fica até mais organizada, com uma constraint representando cada chave separadamente.

No fim das contas, com as alterações que eu citei, seu script ficaria assim:

```
CREATE TABLE situacao (
id_situacao INTEGER NOT NULL,
situacao VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT situacao_id_situacao_PK PRIMARY KEY (id_situacao)
);

CREATE TABLE socio (
id_socio  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
nome         VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,  
cpf          CHAR(11) NOT NULL,
email        VARCHAR(256),
id_situacao  INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT socio_cpf_UN UNIQUE(cpf),
CONSTRAINT socio_id_situacao_FK FOREIGN KEY (id_situacao) REFERENCES situacao (id_situacao)
);

CREATE TABLE marca (
id_marca     INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
marca        VARCHAR (128) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE carro (
id_carro    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
modelo      VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
cor         VARCHAR(64),        
placa       VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
id_socio    INTEGER,
id_marca    INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT  carro_placa_UN UNIQUE (placa),
CONSTRAINT  carro_socio_FK FOREIGN KEY (id_socio) REFERENCES socio 
(id_socio),
CONSTRAINT  carro_marca_FK FOREIGN KEY (id_marca) REFERENCES marca 
(id_marca)
);
```

Comment: Obrigado, provavelmente seria reprovado por causa desses erros, acho que sua correção ficou perfeitamente funcional ao que pede o enunciado

Comment: Que bom que ajudei. Por favor, marque minha resposta como correta se ela realmente te serviu e boa sorte.

Comment: sempre o mesmo tipo da chave referenciada, no caso, INTEGER

Comment: uma chave estrangeira tem que referenciar a um campo do mesmo tipo

Comment: teria que ser INTEGER então né, desculpa kk estou no começo do aprendizado

Comment: sim, teria. Se tiver mais dúvidas, por favor abra um novo tópico pra não prolongarmos muito a sessão de comentário.